# Поиск потомков конкретного элемента jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Подскажите,как правильно собирать элементы принадлежащие к определённой группе.  Есть некая `HTML`-структура типа

```
<div class="sub-group">
<div class="add_protokol_redact_add-sub-group">
    <div class="sub-group_pos">
        <input class="name-bool  pos_name_sub" readonly="" value="Позиция1" data-free="false" data-few="false" data-type="tags" data-optional="false">
        <div class="sub-group_add_input">
            <div class="sub-group_add_input_tags">
                <div class="create_tags_input">
                    <div class="valTags-content">
                        <div class="valTags-main">
                            <input class="valTags tags_add_label" size="1" readonly="" value="1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="valTags-content">
                        <div class="valTags-main">
                            <input class="valTags tags_add_label" size="1" readonly="" value="2">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Мне надо собрать для каждого `sub-group` значения  valTags в группы для каждого  `sub-group_pos` ( количество элементов с классом `sub-group_pos` от 1 до n) 
но при сборе у меня получается что я собираю все значения valTags и записываю их значения для каждого из `sub-group_pos`.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.edit_priem_head_save button', function() {
  var page = {};
  var page_des = {};
  var name_page = $('.add_protokol_add_name_input').val();
  var description_page = $('input.add_protokol_description_name_input').val();
  page_des.protokol_name = name_page;
  page_des.protokol_description = description_page;
  var spes_value = [];
  var tags_mas = [];


  var protocol = {
    'protocol': {
      'protocol_descr': {},
      'protocol_body': []
    }
  };



  $('.add_protokol_add_specialist_tag-order').find('.active_tab').each(function() {
    spes_value += $(this).text() + ",";
  });


  page_des.protocol_access = spes_value;
  page.protokol_description = page_des;
  //steps

  $(".sub-group").each(function() {
    var group = {
      'group': []
    };
    var nameGroup = [];
    $(".add_protokol_redact_add-sub-group").each(function() {
      $(".sub-group_pos").each(function() {
        var submass = {
          'group_name': 'name',
          'position': []
        };
        $(".group_names").each(function() {


          //pos_name_sub

        });
        $(this).parent().find(".pos_name_sub").each(function() {
          var data_type = $(this).attr('data-type');

          var textTags = [];


          switch (data_type) {
            case 'tags':
              console.log("ДАЭТО КЭЙС!!");

              $(this).parent().find(".valTags").each(function() {
                textTags = $(this).val();
                var mark = 'false';
                var optional = 'true';
                var mass_one = {
                  'value': textTags,
                  'mark': mark,
                  'optional': optional
                };

                submass.position.push(mass_one);

                //    tags_mas.push(mass_one);
              });

              break;

          }
          group.group.push(submass);




        });

        submass = null;
      })
    });
    protocol.protocol.protocol_body.push(group);


    summTask = nameGroup;
  });


  console.log("Массивы:", protocol /*tags_mas*/ );
  /*
   var data_json={ "protocol": { "protocol_descr": { "protocol_name": "test" },"protocol_body":[ {"group": {"group_name": "test group","position_info": { "position_name": "1", "position_type": "tags","position_value": "some,value", "data-free":"false","data-type":"false","data-optional":"false"}}}]}};
       data_json.protocol.protocol_body.push({ "group": {"group_name": "test group",  "position_info": {"position_name": "2","position_type": "tags2", "position_value": "some,value2", "data-free":"false","data-type":"false", "data-optional":"false"  }}});
    //   console.log(data_json);
    * */

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-group">
  <input class="name-bool group_names" value="гр1" readonly="" data-optional="false">
  <div class="add_protokol_redact_add-sub-group">
    <div class="sub-group_pos">
      <input class="name-bool  pos_name_sub" readonly="" value="п1" data-free="false" data-few="false" data-type="tags" data-optional="false">
      <div class="sub-group_add_input">
        <div class="sub-group_add_input_tags">
          <div class="create_tags_input">
            <div class="valTags-content">
              <div class="valTags-main">
                <input class="valTags tags_add_label" size="2" readonly="" value="м1">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="valTags-content">
              <div class="valTags-main">
                <input class="valTags tags_add_label" size="2" readonly="" value="м2">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="edit_priem_template_string_add plus" style="float: none; width: 20px; height: 26px; padding-left: 2px;">
          <p class="edit_priem_template_string_add_span" style="float: none;">➕</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sub_del_pos">✖</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-group_pos">
      <input class="name-bool  pos_name_sub" readonly="" value="п2" data-free="false" data-few="false" data-type="tags" data-optional="false">
      <div class="sub-group_add_input">
        <div class="sub-group_add_input_tags">
          <div class="create_tags_input">
            <div class="valTags-content">
              <div class="valTags-main">
                <input class="valTags tags_add_label" size="2" readonly="" value="м3">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="edit_priem_template_string_add plus" style="float: none; width: 20px; height: 26px; padding-left: 2px;">
          <p class="edit_priem_template_string_add_span" style="float: none;">➕</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sub_del_pos">✖</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="add_protokol_redact_add-sub-group_content"></div>
</div>
```

Подскажите как правильно пробежаться по дереву, буду так же рад ссылкам на пример или статью.

Answer (score 1):

Я нашёл решение, для поиска внутри конкретного элемента я использовал `$(this).parent().find(".valTags").each(function (){})` - это позволило собирать данные именно внутри текущего родительского элемента.

Answer (score 0):

Коряво, жуть, но вроде работает :-)

```js
let found = $(".sub-group").find($(".sub-group_pos"));//Получаем массив .sub-group, с элементами с наличием класса .sub-group_pos
//console.log(found);//массив в консоли
let indexed = found.each(function() {
 this[0] = $(this).find($('.valTags'));
});//каждый элемент становится массивом, в котором первым элементом будет массив элементов класса .valTags 
//console.log(indexed);//массив в консоли
indexed.each(function () {
 this[0].each(function () {
  console.log($(this).val());// в каждом первом элементе массива собираем значения элементов и в консоль
 });
});
//Если требуется найти значения только, к примеру пятнадцатого элемента,то 
// функция будет вроде:
// function valTagsIndexedElement (number) {
//  indexed[number][0].each(function () {
//   console.log($(this).val())
//  });
// };
// valTagsIndexedElement (1);
```

```html
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-group">
  <div class="add_protokol_redact_add-sub-group">
    <div class="sub-group_pos">
       <input class="name-bool  pos_name_sub" readonly="" value="Позиция1" data-free="false" data-few="false" data-type="tags" data-optional="false">
          <div class="sub-group_add_input">
            <div class="sub-group_add_input_tags">
               <div class="create_tags_input">
                   <div class="valTags-content">
                      <div class="valTags-main">
                        <input class="valTags tags_add_label" size="1" readonly="" value="14">
                      </div>
                      <div class="valTags-main">
                        <input class="valTags tags_add_label" size="1" readonly="" value="1">
                      </div>
                      <div class="valTags-main">
                        <input class="valTags tags_add_label" size="1" readonly="" value="1">
                      </div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="valTags-content">
                     <div class="valTags-main">
                       <input class="valTags tags_add_label" size="1" readonly="" value="2">
                     </div>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-group_pos"><input class="valTags tags_add_label" size="1" readonly="" value="2"></div> <!--проверочный блок -->
  </div>
</div>
```